# Почему не работает UI после ipa-restore?

Tags: linux, ldap

Подскажите, пожалуйста, перекидывал бекап данных с freeipa 4.6.8 на 4.9.2, бекап успешно загрузился, но теперь не заходит в UI, пишет ошибку **"Не удалось войти по неизвестной причине"**
В логе /var/log/httpd/error_log:

```
[Thu Jun 10 18:49:28.385434 2021] [suexec:notice] [pid 6507:tid 140267804797248] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Thu Jun 10 18:49:28.445450 2021] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 6507:tid 140267804797248] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Thu Jun 10 18:49:28.452657 2021] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 6507:tid 140267804797248] AH00489: Apache/2.4.37 (centos) OpenSSL/1.1.1k mod_auth_gssapi/1.6.1 mod_wsgi/4.6.4 Python/3.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Jun 10 18:49:28.452676 2021] [core:notice] [pid 6507:tid 140267804797248] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Thu Jun 10 18:49:31.927376 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 6515:tid 140267804797248] ipa: INFO: *** PROCESS START ***
[Thu Jun 10 18:49:31.933140 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 6513:tid 140267804797248] ipa: INFO: *** PROCESS START ***
[Thu Jun 10 18:49:32.032685 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 6516:tid 140267804797248] ipa: INFO: *** PROCESS START ***
[Thu Jun 10 18:49:32.069246 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 6514:tid 140267804797248] ipa: INFO: *** PROCESS START ***
[Thu Jun 10 18:49:38.656397 2021] [auth_gssapi:error] [pid 6519:tid 140266703005440] [client 172.20.0.131:34842] GSS ERROR gss_acquire_cred[_from]() failed to get server creds: [Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information ( SPNEGO cannot find mechanisms to negotiate)]
[Thu Jun 10 18:49:38.657668 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 6515:tid 140266919876352] [remote 10.8.20.49:58049] ipa: INFO: 401 Unauthorized: No session cookie found
```

Вывод команды ipa -v ping

```
[root@ipa01 ~]# ipa -v ping
ipa: ERROR: No valid Negotiate header in server response
```

Пробовал перезапуск ПО, ОС(CentOS 8), очистка кеша sssd

Comment: Поверхностное гугление выдаёт такое: https://serverfault.com/a/991267/315697